# Problems generating random data in SQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new using mySQL, so probably my question will be very banal, but I didn't find any solution on internet.

I have two tables, TABLE 1 and TABLE 2, each one with a single primary key tab1PK (INT) and tab2PK (VARCHAR).

Since TABLE 1 and TABLE 2 have a M:N relationship, I have a third table, TABLE 3, whose PK are two: **tab1PK** and **tab2PK**.

I generated random data for TABLE 1 and TABLE 1. Is there a way to generate rapidly data for the TABLE 3? Is there a way to easily combine **tab1PK** and **tab2PK**?

Comment: insert into table3 select <<>> from table1 join table2  should work. Not an exact syntax. Just for reference.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? Does the relations needs in pair inqueness? Does each possible pair must present in junction table?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a cartesian join of all table1 & table2 primary keys.

```
insert into table3 (tab1PK, tab2PK)
select table1.tab1PK, table2.tab2PK
from table1, table2
```